# How to determine the page size of a PDF document in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, document

When I say "Page size" i mean for example "A4" or "US Letter" (which might just be called "Letter").  I am producing PDFs programatically and need to test that they came out in the right format.

Is there a command line function for this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get this from `pdfinfo`, e.g.:

```sh
$ pdfinfo mydoc.pdf | grep 'Page size'
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
```

Comment: Nice... but what if I want it in inches or mm instead of pts ?